# How to deploy sym linked files with GAE Flex

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I have a GAE flexible app that shares files with another GAE app (these are different apps and not modules of a single app).  To avoid duplicate files, I use sym links.

With GAE standard this worked fine, but with GAE flexible, the sym links are deployed as sym links.  This breaks my app, because where the links point to is outside of the app.

With GAE flexible, is it possible to replace symlinks with what they are pointing to on deployment?

Comment: Apologies for the stupid question... what's in your `requirements.txt`? Does it include `Flask-Common`? And are you `pip install --requirement requirements.txt` **before** deploying it? As you likely know, Flex just containerizes then runs your app so there's no reason for it not to work. If the container build works (if it's in GCR), you can pull it and run it locally to test that.

Comment: @DazWilkin, flask_common.py is my own code that should be deployed with my app.  It is actually a sym link, and it turns out that GAE flex doesn't work as I expected for sym links.  I just rewrote my question to focus on the true problem.  Thanks for your comment.